# android facebook post on wall not working

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I have one trouble with posting on the facebook wall. I using facebook SDK and my code is below.

below code asking: myApp would you like to post your behalf. But nothing posted on my fb wall. Please give me advice how do i post on facebook wall. I want to post static text from my app. For example String message = "Hello all"; will posted on my wall from my app.

```
    private void publishStory() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null){

        // Check for publish permissions    
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return;
        }

        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
        postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
        postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
        postParams.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
        postParams.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

        Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                           .getGraphObject()
                                           .getInnerJSONObject();
                String postId = null;
                try {
                    postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.i("HERE",
                        "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                }
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                         error.getErrorMessage(),
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                             postId,
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };

        Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, 
                              HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
    }

}

private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if (!superset.contains(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common mistake. The problem is that requestNewPublishPermissions is an asynchronous request. The method returns right away, but you won't actually get the permissions until later (after the user is prompted). What's happening here is that you're making the publish request immediately, but you haven't acquired the permissions yet.

What you need to do is save the state when you request new permissions, and when you get the callback that you've gotten new permissions, try the request then.

Have a look in the HelloFacebook sample app that demonstrates this strategy.